# Need good examples of riverside films

Tags: shortfilm, short, examples

I'm actually working on the sound design of a short film.

There are 2 main characters, a young married couple. The man is fly-fishing in a small river, and his wife is embroiding on the bank at the same time. It's all about couple psychology.
Also, the director wants me to treat the sound of the river almost as a character.

Are there great examples of feature films that would be inspiring in this case ?

Answer (score 7):

You HAVE to watch "A river runs trough it". Its about fly fishing as well.
The sound designer and Re recording mixer was Gary Rydstrom.
It sounds gorgeous and its an awesome film over all.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've seen it, but The River Wild featured a fairly dynamic and large river. Some of the earlier more serene scenes before they hit the rapids and whirlpools might be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Apocalypse Now (one of the best movies for sound) has a lot of scenes that take place on the river. I'd check it out as a reference.

Cheers!